# WordPress/WooCommerce: Adding product_variation to the search parameters is pulling up draft products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce store for makeup, and we need to make it so that variation names are searchable, since people will often be looking for a specific shade name. I'm using this bit of code to make the product variations searchable:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_woocommerce_product_variations' );

function search_woocommerce_product_variations( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() && is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'product', 'product_variation' ) );
    }
}
```

Edited to add: I've already tried adding this in, with no changes in the search results:

```
$query->set('post_status', array('publish'));
```

The problem is that when searching on the name of a variation it's pulling up products that do that have that search term in the variation name, but are currently set to Draft status. How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell the query which post_status your looking for:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_woocommerce_product_variations' );

function search_woocommerce_product_variations( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() && is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'product', 'product_variation' ) );
        $query->set('post_status', array('publish'));  
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, guess I should have included that in the post - I tried that already, no joy.

Comment: I've checked on several Woo instances, this should work, could you check the statuses of the variations, these could be set to inherit, or could there be another query alt in your site?

Comment: Looks like you were right, all the variations have their post_status set to "publish". 

Any guesses on why their post_status's might be like that? I just loaded up my dev server with a copy of the site, set the theme to 2021, disabled every plugin but WooCommerce, and then created a new product with some variations - even keeping the product itself as a draft on the first save, the variations still show a post_status of "publish" in the DB. I tried different things like publishing, then seting back to draft, etc. The only thing that works is unchecking "Enabled" on the variation.

Comment: It's a known issue: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/15812

Comment: I'm not able to look rn, but maybe getting the post_status of the parent in a sub query?

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the solution, since it appears to be a known bug with WooCommerce - we'll probably just end up editing all the variations, either by hand or programatically. Sucks that Woo has no interest in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'numberposts' => -1,
);
$products = get_posts( $args );


foreach($products as $product):
$product_s = wc_get_product( $product->ID );
if ($product_s->product_type == 'variable') {
    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => $plan->ID,
        'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
        'numberposts' => -1,
    );
    $variations = $product_s->get_available_variations();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($variations);
    echo '</pre>';
}
endforeach;
?>
```